# Backstop js - pass url parameter

Tags: javascript, backstop.js

I wrote a script which is running my tests.
I am using it like this. currentSpec is a path, action is reference or test, filter is for running only some of the scenarios. But how can I dynamically set url here? Or Can I somehow do it in onBefore (onReady) script?

```
backstop(action, {
    config: currentSpec,
    filter: cmd.scenario
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found this. I ended up writing custom test runner.

http://fivemilemedia.co.uk/blog/backstopjs-javascript-configuration